# ¿Se debe modificar una respuesta aceptada por otras dudas del autor de la pregunta?

Tags: discusión, convenciones-sociales, respuesta-aceptada

Me ha sucedido más de una vez que he contestado de forma concisa lo que el usuario está solicitando, pero luego hace un comentario pidiendo una modificación del funcionamiento. En algunos casos la modificación es mínima y se puede agregar sin problemas a la respuesta, pero en otros conlleva una reescritura completa del código.

Por ejemplo: [Descargar archivos consecutivos python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/304979/80870)

La modificación que el usuario sugiere requiere módulos multi-hilo y al menos una función, por lo tanto la respuesta va a ser bien diferente a la que ya fue aceptada. Entonces, 
¿Se debe editar la respuesta, agregando el nuevo código? ¿Se debe escribir una nueva respuesta para no interferir con la que resuelve la duda original? ¿O directamente ignorar la nueva solicitud?

Comment: Si la pregunta original no incluía los "nuevos requerimientos" el "deber ser" es solicitarle al AP que publique una nueva pregunta pero si por cualquier razón decides publicar el nuevo código que es completamente diferente al "viejo", es mejor hacerlo en una nueva respuesta

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo con @Rubén. Si los requerimientos cambian de tal forma que la respuesta es diferente, se debería formular una nueva pregunta con los nuevos requerimientos. En todo caso lo recomendable es pedirle al OP que redacte una nueva pregunta, y si la respuesta de la misma se relaciona con la primera, se incluye el `link` como relacionada. Así se puede seguir el hilo y la coherencia de una con otra.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Las preguntas no se deben *reutilizar*:

Ciclo de vida de una pregunta: **Alguien (OP) expone una duda o problema y alguien (OP u otra persona) responde, resolviendo la duda.** El OP puede marcar la respuesta como *aceptada* si lo considera conveniente.

Eso es todo, una vez se tiene una respuesta, el OP no debe modificar la pregunta porque una respuesta válida puede pasar a ser incorrecta, y alguien que visite después dicha pregunta podría votar negativo esa respuesta al no darse cuenta de las modificaciones.

Si una respuesta causa nuevas dudas, OP debe crear nuevas preguntas. Es la forma correcta y esperada por las normas del sitio para recopilar y compartir conocimientos entre los usuarios.

La única excepción a este escenario que se me ocurre es el siguiente escenario:

1. La pregunta se ha escrito de manera ambigua
2. Alguien no se da cuenta de esta ambigüedad o decide asumir algo que la elimina y responde.
3. OP se da cuenta de la ambigüedad y corrige la pregunta, añadiendo detalles.
4. La respuesta ahora es incorrecta, porque la suposición que se hizo era incorrecta.

En este caso el que realmente se equivocó fue la persona que respondió, porque la pregunta original era candidata a ser cerrada con los motivos *Demasiado amplia* o *No está claro lo que se pregunta* y debió comentar al respecto o (si no tiene reputación para comentar) votar para cerrar, en lugar de responder precipitadamente.